# Import packages latex from directory

Tags: latex

Is it possibile in latex to import a package like IEEEtran which I don't have installed but I have inside a directory named IEEETran_dir?

For instance I would like to do something like

```
\usepackage{./IEEEtran_dir/IEEEtran}

\documentclass[10pt, conference, letterpaper]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In theory something like `\documentclass[10pt, conference, letterpaper]{./IEEEtran_dir/IEEEtran}` could work, but you will face problems with all additional files that the class might load. So it would be better to allow tex to find the class file for you by either a) installing the package properly b) placing the package in your personal texmf tree or c) adding the `IEEEtran_dir` to the `TEXINPUTS` path

Comment: Thanks, passing the path directly inside the \documentclass is working. But yes it asks for additional packages. I'll try to install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically like it was suggested in the comment the proper way to do so was to import the relative path of the package directly in the \documentclass statement.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, letterpaper]{./IEEEtran_dir/IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Of course it's just a workaround for those cases where you cannot install it, but the correct way should be to install the package.